# ASP.NET MVC 3 and HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

I'm using the .net membership in an MVC 3 (razor) application.

I've implemented a custom profile class where I use HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name to get the membership user.

```
public class UserProfile : ProfileBase
{
    static public UserProfile CurrentUser
    {
        get {
               return (UserProfile)(ProfileBase.Create(Membership.GetUser(new Guid(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name)).UserName)); 
            }
    }

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return ((string)(base["FirstName"])); }
        set { base["FirstName"] = value; Save(); }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return ((string)(base["LastName"])); }
        set { base["LastName"] = value; Save(); }
    }
}
```

As you can see in the above class, I have to cast HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name as a GUID to get the membership user.

The question is, why after the login validation, in the HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name I get the GUID value (userID) and not the username?

Is that normal?

Answer (score 0):

Just use Membership.GetUser() to get the current user.

Comment: Membership.GetUser() is null even though HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is true.
Of course before to run the profile class, in another class I execute the membership validation 
`Membership.ValidateUser(email, password)`
I don't know what's wrong. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using default .NET membership, (FormAuthentication with default GenericPrincipal, FormsIdentity) and you have created your MVC application from the default 'Internet Application' template, then:

Check your 'LogOn' Action method of the AccountController. One possible cause of altering the userName to the UserId(GUID) value is to set the Auth-cookie to 'ProviderUserKey' as userName, like:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
        {
            var user = Membership.GetUser(model.UserName);
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.ProviderUserKey.ToString(), model.RememberMe);

            //...
            return Redirect(Url.Content("~/"));
        }
        else{
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```